# Multiplication map of group object and the projections

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a (locally small) category with finite products. Then we have an equivalence of definitions:

(1) $Y \in \mathscr{A}$ is a group object (i.e. with structure maps $m: Y \times Y \to Y$, $e: * \to Y$, and $i: Y \to Y$ and some commutative diagrams);

(2) $\mathscr{A}(-,Y)$ has valued in $\mathbf{Grp}$.

If we assume (1), then it can be shown directly that $\mathscr{A}(X,Y)$ forms a group (canonically), with the evident multiplication $f \cdot g$ given as $X \xrightarrow{\Delta} X \times X \xrightarrow{f \times g} Y \times Y \xrightarrow {m} Y$ and evdient identity element $X \to * \xrightarrow{e} Y$.

Now assuming (2). [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367370/equivalence-of-definitions-of-group-object-using-the-yoneda-lemma) post argues that the Yoneda Lemma provides the necessary structure maps for $Y$ to be a group object. But I think we can do this more explicitly. The group structures on $\mathscr{A}(X,Y)$ should force us to define $m,e,i$ in a particular way. Suppose $m,e,i$ exist and let's see what they have to look like. To begin, we can recover the group structure $\mathscr{A}(X,Y)$ by means of the construction in the last paragraph. In particular, the identity element of $\mathscr{A}(X,Y)$ is the arrow $X \to * \xrightarrow{e} Y$, and in particular, $e$ must be the identity element in $\mathscr{A}(*,Y)$, because $*$ is terminal. Now let’s try to get the map $m$.  We apply the multiplication rule to $f = g = e$ to get the arrow
$$* \to * \times * \xrightarrow{e \times e} Y \times Y \xrightarrow{m} Y$$
But $e$ is the identity element, so this composition must be the same as $e$. But now here is the issue: there seems to be two choices of the map $m$, which seems so unnatural:

[image]

To make the composition into $e$, we can either pick $m = p_1$ or $m = p_2$, but the two projections are by no means to be equal. But at least we know $m$ must relate to the projections in some way. And at this stage, I'm not sure how to look for a correct definition of $m$, perhaps the group object axioms can shine some light on it, but I'm not sure.

For the map $i$, I guess it would be the inverse of $1_Y$ in $\mathscr{A}(Y,Y)$ but not sure.

Let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: How is $e$ defined if you assume (2)?

Comment: $e$ is defined here to be the identity element of the group $\mathscr{A}(*,Y)$. This is the (informal) argument I used: if $e$ actually exists, then it is only possible to define $e$ this way (shown above) so that the resulting group object induces group structures on the morphism sets that coincide with the given group structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last diagram commutes: $p_i \circ \Delta = \operatorname{id}$ by the definition of $\Delta$ and $p_i \circ f_1 \times f_2 = f_i \circ p_i$, again by the definition of $f_1 \times f_2$.

The universal property of $X \times Y$ is that given $f \colon Z \to X$ and $g \colon Z \to Y$, there is a unique map $u \colon Z \to X \times Y$ such that $p_1 \circ u = f$ and $p_2 \circ u = g$. For convenience, we'll notate this unique map as $\langle f, g \rangle$.

$\Delta \colon X \to X \times X$ is defined as $\langle \operatorname{id}_X, \operatorname{id}_X \rangle$, so by definition, both $p_1 \circ \Delta$ and $p_2 \circ \Delta$ are $\operatorname{id}_X$. This means that the upper left and upper right triangles of your diagram commute.

Given $f \colon X \to Y$ and $g \colon Z \to W$, $f \times g \colon X \times Z \to Y \times W$ is defined as $\langle f \circ p_1, g \circ p_2 \rangle$. So by definition, $p_1 \circ f \times g = p_1 \circ \langle f \circ p_1, g \circ p_2 \rangle = f \circ p_1$ and $p_2 \circ f \times g = p_2 \circ \langle f \circ p_1, g \circ p_2 \rangle = g \circ p_2$. In particular, $p_i \circ e \times e = e \circ p_i$, so the lower left and lower right squares in your diagram commute.

Since each section of your diagram commutes, so does the whole thing.

---

As for defining $m$ and $i$, I think the Yoneda version sheds some light on things. Since $\mathscr A (X, Y)$ is a group for each $X$, we have binary operations $\mathscr A (X, Y) \times \mathscr A (X, Y) \to \mathscr A (X, Y)$ taking the pair $(f, g)$ to $f \cdot g$.

$\mathscr A (X, Y) \times \mathscr A (X, Y) \cong \mathscr A (X, Y \times Y)$ by the universal property of $Y \times Y$, with the map $\mathscr A (X, Y) \times \mathscr A (X, Y) \to \mathscr A (X, Y \times Y)$ taking the pair $(f, g)$ to $\langle f, g \rangle$ and the map $\mathscr A (X, Y \times Y) \to \mathscr A (X, Y) \times \mathscr A (X, Y)$ taking $h$ to the pair $(p_1 \circ h, p_2 \circ h)$.

That means we also have a map $\mathscr A (X, Y \times Y) \to \mathscr A (X, Y)$ taking $h$ to $(p_1 \circ h) \cdot (p_2 \circ h)$. Yoneda then tells us to evaluate this at the identity to get our map $m \colon Y \times Y \to Y$, giving $(p_1 \circ \operatorname{id}_{Y \times Y}) \cdot (p_2 \circ \operatorname{id}_{Y \times Y}) = p_1 \cdot p_2$.

Something similar applies to finding $i$, and I think you have the right idea.

---

To show that this map $m$ is forced (without directly appealing to Yoneda), we can use similar reasoning to your argument for the uniqueness of $e$. You started from the equation $e_X = e \circ !_X$, where $e_X$ is the identity of $\mathscr A (X, Y)$ and $!_X$ is the terminal map from $X$. I *think* you're arguing that since $!_*$ is the identity, $e$ must be $e_*$, because $e = e \circ !_* = e_*$ (it's not clear to me what line of reasoning is contained in the phrase "because $*$ is terminal").

For $m$, our starting equation is $f \cdot g = m \circ f \times g \circ \Delta$, which can be rewritten as $m \circ \langle f, g \rangle$. As before, we want $\langle f, g \rangle$ to be the identity so as to get an equation for $m$. For this to be true, we need $f = p_1$ and $g = p_2$, since e.g. $f = p_1 \circ \langle f, g \rangle = p_1 \circ \operatorname{id}_{Y \times Y}$.

Thus, $m = m \circ \langle p_1, p_2 \rangle = p_1 \cdot p_2$, which is what we got for $m$ before.

Comment: If we define $m = p_1 \cdot p_2$, then wouldn't defining $m = p_2 \cdot p_1$ also work (by "flipping" all the diagrams)? But the group $\mathscr{A}(Y \times Y,Y)$ is by no means to be abelian.

Comment: Not if you want $m \circ \langle f, g \rangle$ to be $f \cdot g$ (I thought that was the goal). Obviously there isn't a unique group structure on $Y$ *period*, merely a unique structure that induces the same group structures on $\mathscr A(X, Y)$ (and indeed, as you point out, the opposite group structure is a different structure if it isn't abelian). $p_2 \cdot p_1 \circ \langle f, g \rangle$ = $(p_2  \circ \langle f, g \rangle) \cdot (p_1  \circ \langle f, g \rangle) = g \cdot f$, so defining $m$ like that indeed reverses the operation.